# A new language, how to auto-complete in windows vim?

Tags: windows, vim, autocomplete, exuberant-ctags

I'm using Gvim in windows.

Normally, when we type some character then press `Ctrl-n`, vim will show some `tag`, but those `tags` just includes words which have been pre-typed in the current file.

Now, I need it working in a new language, and show the `tag` which has been defined in other files.

So, I create a new `\\.ctags` for this new language, and generate tags file by `exuberant-ctags`. 
I can choose a function in current file, then press `Ctrl-]` to jump to the function definition, but this function was define in the other files. It is working very well.

I don't know how to make it show the tags which are generated by `ctags` when I type some character.

Please help me. Thanks very much.

My English is poor, I hope you can understand what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL-N is just the default completion (which completes from a variety of sources, including the open buffers and also the tags database). There are many more specialized completions (all starting with CTRL-X), among them *tags completion*, triggered via CTRL-X CTRL-], see `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-]`. If you've correctly configured the `'tags'` option (so your tags database is found) and tags jumps do work, just start using that.

Some languages / filetypes also define a language-specific completion (for language keywords etc.), usually via the `'omnifunc'` option and triggered by CTRL-X CTRL-O. You could write such yourself, too.

Comment: Thank you very much. After uninstall vim-autocomplpop plugin, It's working now. Maybe vim-autocomplpop plugin have some problems. You answers are very awesome. Now i know more vim command.